# Instruction format in direct addressing mode

Tags: cpu-architecture, machine-code, instruction-set, immediate-operand

Assume a computer with a 16-bit memory and 16-bit data and address bus. So if an Instruction is of 16-bit
let's say the opcode occupies 6 bits and the operand occupies the remaining 10 bits. In the direct addressing mode, the memory address of the operand is specified in the instruction itself. So how a 16-bit memory location is specified inside the 10-bit instruction operand. Is the address encoded somehow or one Instruction is stored in multiple memory locations? Sorry, If my question seems kind of stupid.

Comment: Generally that's not possible.  If you need an absolute address utilizing the full address-space you need to put it in a register, and use that register as a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I wasn't expecting anybody to answer my question. So, we can use absolute addressing only for the addresses which occupy less than or equal to 10 bits, right?

Comment: It depends on the computer.  In, for example, the pdp-11, one instruction occupies one to three words, depending on whether there are none, one, or two memory addresses.  Technically I suppose you'd say it was indirect or indexed addressing, but not so's you'd have to really notice as a programmer.  `MOV R1,FOO`  means `MOV R1,disp(R7)`, where 'disp' is stored in the second word of this 2-word instruction, and R7 is the program counter.